# Rails assign instance variables in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following in my controller:

```
if params[:option] == "1"
      id = params[:id]
      @resultsReceived = true
      begin
       @pwvav_ratings = Pwvav.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",")
      #or
       @pwbab_ratings = Pwbab.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",")
     #or
       @puvub_ratings = Puvub.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",")
     #or
       @tic_ratings   = Tic.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",")
     rescue
       redirect_to "/view_api", :flash => { :notice => "Sorry, No records returned for #{id}." }
      end
```

I am trying to set each of those instance variables (`@pwvav_ratings`,`@pwbab_ratings`...) to the find if the find is not nil, so that I can call it in my view. How do I check if..or and if nothing is found, rescue with the flash notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
if params[:option] == "1"
  id = params[:id]
  @resultsReceived = true
  @pwvav_ratings = Pwvav.find_by_id(id)
  #or
  @pwbab_ratings = Pwbab.find_by_id(id)
  #or
  @puvub_ratings = Puvub.find_by_id(id)
  #or
  @tic_ratings   = Tic.find_by_id(id)
  unless @pwvav_ratings || @pwbab_ratings || @puvub_ratings || @tic_ratings
    redirect_to "/view_api", :flash => { :notice => "Sorry, No records returned for #{id}." }
  end
end
```

You can call `.recomendation.split(',')` on each variable in your view.

Comment: When I call `.recommendation.split(",").each do ` in my view I get `undefined method recommendation for []:Array`. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: On which variable you are calling `.recomendation.split(',')` ?

Comment: On all of them. I  loop through ` @pwvav_ratings`, `@pwbab_ratings`, `@puvub_ratings` and `@tic_tatings` in my view.

Comment: Is `Recomendation` another model?

Comment: If so then tell me attributes of that model.

Comment: Nope, recommendation is a column I have on each of the rating models. The values in that column are comma separated, hence then split(",").

Comment: try this, `@tic_tatings.first.recommendation.split(",").each do`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of every line. Verifying it's not nil. (Notice `!` but you can also use `not`)

```
@pwvav_ratings = Pwvav.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",") if !Pwvav.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",").nil?
```

Or you can use `unless`

```
@pwvav_ratings = Pwvav.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",") unless Pwvav.find_by_id(id).recommendation.split(",").nil?
```

Comment: It is bad to use that: Maybe the find_by_id will not return any result + You are triggering 2 queries to the DB (one to test, one to do if result exists)

Comment: that's true. i'm assuming it's not returning `nil` in the first place. real answer is to take that down into the model, and either have a `scope` or finder there. test the response, and then do an check if there's something available. This is just a quick and dirty solution.